# React native app not picking right env file [for Android only]

Tags: android, react-native

I have 3 environments setup named prod, dev and staging with separate `.env` files named `.env.prod, .env.staging and .env.dev` and the main `.env` in the root directory.

Then main `.env` file gets populated with the correct env values while running the app on IOS which I expect on android too but it stays unchanged.

When I run the IOS app it picks up env values for the respective scheme and updates the main `.env` file as expected.

But for android it is not picking up env values from the selected android `flavor/build`

I am using following command to run android app

```
react-native run-android --variant=stagingdebug --appId=*****.staging
```

I even added `ENVFILE=.env.staging` in the above command, but still no luck.

`android/app/build.gradle` file:

```
...
project.ext.envConfigFiles = [
   proddebug: ".env.prod",
   prodrelease: ".env.prod",
   devrelease: ".env.dev",
   devdebug: ".env.dev",
   stagingrelease: ".env.staging",
   stagingdebug: ".env.staging"
]
...
android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    flavorDimensions "default"
    productFlavors {
        prod {
            minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
            applicationId "*******"
            targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
            resValue "string", "build_config_package", "*******"
        }
        staging {
            minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
            applicationId "*****.staging"
            targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
            resValue "string", "build_config_package", "******"
        }
        dev {
            minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
            applicationId "******.dev"
            targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
            resValue "string", "build_config_package", "*******"
        }
    }
 ...
```

While running the app it even shows this in the terminal logs:

```
...
> Configure project :app
Reading env from: .env.staging
...
```

Comment: Do you use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-config ?

Comment: Yes @VasylNahuliak, I am using it

Comment: Try rearranging words, for example, `proddebug` should be `debugprod` https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config#android-1

Comment: Still no luck, it even shows this in the terminal while running the app but still don't pick staging variables:

...
 Configure project :app
Reading env from: .env.staging
...

@VasylNahuliak

Comment: Eh, sorry. I recently had a case with `react-native-config` and I find for me the best approach but it's a workaround. I use only one `.env` file and change content when I need it (also on CI/CD). I remove native steps from the documentation (gradle and Podfile). It's easily run from the terminal and IDE (Xcode, Android Studio) the same wave.